# Не удается подключить system.web.optimization

Tags: c#, asp.net

Как это можно понять??
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В контроллере удается подключить пространство, а в представлении нет.Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть

Answer (score 1):

Толком не понял из-за чего это произошло, то ли в Intellisense, то ли в самой студии что-то случилось.В общем после перезапуска проекта все стало нормально

Answer (score 0):

Обычно это происходит и за того что когда запускается проект, по какой то причине не загружаются все библиотеки.

Вот на скрине есть первый столбец с иерархией папок, там вы зачеркнули красным папку которая не работает. На случай если такое ещё будет, а оно будет и не только с этой библиотекой, то просто нажимаете `мышью > правый клик > Reload` (или перезагрузить), и всё.

Или перезапуск проекта, это тоже самое только перезапуск всего проекта полечается